# How to get all element in list after matched string in python

Tags: python, list

Let say I have a list:

```
list1 = ['abc','a','e','i','o','abc','l','m','n']
```

May I know how to get all the element after 'abc' and group or makes sublist of it including 'abc' itself?

The result become:

```
[['abc','a','e','i','o'],['abc','l','m','n']]
```

I have tried this but it is not like what I want:

```
  lineslist=[]
  for line in list1:
    if line.startswith('abc'):
       linelist.append(line)

     else:
        linelist.append(line)
```

Comment: `list1 = [abc,a,e,i,o,abc,l,m,n]` is not a valid python code.

Comment: I assume all the elements are strings? Your two lines with examples don't show them as string, but your code block does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straightforwardly:

```
lst = ['abc','a','e','i','o','abc','l','m','n']
res = []
for s in lst:
    if s == 'abc':
        res.append([])
    if res: res[-1].append(s)
print(res)
```

The output:

```
[['abc', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o'], ['abc', 'l', 'm', 'n']]
```

Comment: only problem that could happen with this beautiful code is the list don't start wit `abc`.

Comment: @ElegantOdoo, I had such a thought, but I was waiting the OP may noted that. Anyway, see my update

Comment: Ohhhh how do you get this idea, You are a true Pythonista

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way:

```
>>> lst = ['abc','a','e','i','o','abc','l','m','n']
>>> seps = [i for i in range(len(lst)) if lst[i] == 'abc']
>>> if len(seps) :
...     seps.append( len(lst) )
>>> print [lst[a:b] for a,b in zip(seps, seps[1:])]
[['abc', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o'], ['abc', 'l', 'm', 'n']]
```